# Gauss theorem - Do we get this space?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

Using Gauss theorem I want to calculate $\iint_{\Sigma}f\cdot N\ dA$ where $\Sigma$ is the closed boundary surface of the bounded space that is defined by the surfaces with equations $x=y^2$, $x=9$, $z=0$, $x=z$, and $f(x,y,z)=(3x-5y, 4z-2y, 8yz)$ and the perpendicular vectors $N$ direct to the outside of the space.

$$$$

From Gauss theorem we have that $$\iint_{\Sigma}f\cdot N\ dA=\iiint_{\Omega}\nabla \cdot f\ dV$$

We have that $$\nabla \cdot f=\frac{\partial{(3x-5y)}}{ \partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{(4z-2y)}}{ \partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{(8yz)}}{ \partial{z}}=3+(-2)+8y=1+8y$$

It is left to get the boundaries for the right integral.

Do we get $\Omega=\{(x,y,z) \mid 0\leq x\leq 9, -\sqrt{x}\leq y\leq \sqrt{x}, 0\leq z\leq x\}$ ?

Comment: Yes.  But I think I'd make the order of integration $-3\leq y \leq 3$ then $y^2\leq x \leq 9$.

Comment: Then we get: $$\int_{-3}^3\int_{y^2}^9\int_0^x (1+8y)dzdxdy=\int_{-3}^3\int_{y^2}^9\left ([ z+8yz]_{z=0}^x\right )dxdy=\int_{-3}^3\int_{y^2}^9( x+8yx)dxdy=\int_{-3}^3\left (\left [\frac{x^2}{2}+4yx^2\right ]_{x=y^2}^9\right )dy=\int_{-3}^3\left (\frac{81}{2}+324y-\frac{y^4}{2}-4y^5\right )dy=\left [\frac{81}{2}y+162y^2-\frac{y^5}{10}-\frac{2}{3}y^6\right ]_{-3}^3=\left [\frac{81}{2}\cdot 3+162\cdot 3^2-\frac{3^5}{10}-\frac{2}{3}\cdot 3^6\right ]-\left [\frac{81}{2}\cdot (-3)+162\cdot (-3)^2-\frac{(-3)^5}{10}-\frac{2}{3}\cdot (-3)^6\right ]=81\cdot 3-\frac{3^5}{5}=\frac{972}{5}$$ @B.Goddard

Comment: The given result is $-\frac{100959}{35}$. What have I done wrong?  @B.Goddard

Comment: The divergence is $1+8y$.  The $8y$ should contribute $0$ to the integral because the region is symmetric about the $xz$-plane.  So we're integrating $1$ over the region and that should give the volume of the region.  I don't see how the answer could be negative.  Maybe the given result is wrong or you mis-copied the problem(?)

Comment: The problem is as I wrote it. So, what I have done in the comment above is correct, right? @B.Goddard

Comment: I believe so.  I worked it a different way and got the same answer.  Also, their answer has a factor of $7$ in the denominator.  At no point do we integrate a 5th power or 5/2 power which might put a $7$ in the denominator.  All the coefficients in the beginning are integers, so where did this 7 come from?